# Logical Left shift

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded, cpu-architecture

```
mov r0, 0x9
mov r1,r0,LSL #1
```

this is my code. The updated value of R1 after executing both the lines is 12. Shouldn't it be 2?
because:

9 : 0 1 0 0 1

LSL by 1 bit

: 1 0 0 1 0

where the left most bit goes to cpsr? please help me.

Comment: You don't have a 4 bit computer, do you? What you really have in `r0` is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001` so shifting that left will give you `0x12` (hex).

Comment: Recall that the register has 32 bits, not 4.

Comment: While it is common for fundamental principles of computing to be explained using 4-bit values, few _real_ computers work on 4-bit registers! Perhaps the microcontroller in your electric toothbrush. Certainly not ARM.  You are expected to extrapolate these fundamentals to real devices, not take them literally.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!